# CSS Navigation left side gap

Tags: css, navigation, nav

Okay so I have a navigation bar that follows your screen as your scroll down and up however it shows on the left side that its not touching. I have no margin to it either and don't understand why it is doing this can someone please help. Thanks

here is the css for navigation
http://pastebin.com/QTWcTa8H
It is a long list so I put it on pastebin

And here is the html code for the navigation

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="nav_wrapper" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">link 2 a</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">link 2 b</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">link 2 c</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bh9L/1/

Comment: Please post your codes here, and make a JSFiddle too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add,

```
body {
    margin: 0;  /* reset default margin and padding it to zero */
    padding: 0; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/6bh9L/2/)**

OR,

You can add

```
#nav { 
   left: 0  // will pull to left (with respect to viewport). 
}
```

Comment: @Ash You can even do it with `left:0` on your `position:fixed` element. Please accept the ans if it works for you